# Splitting a big dataset into smaller groups

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, dataset

I am trying to split a large dataset with 1.7 million data into 3 columns and assign a group number to every 2500 data to be able to analyze each group separately and compare it with other groups. For example, I want to calculate RMS of each group and plot them at the end to see their behavior.
I used the following code, found from the forum, but it didn't work for me:

```
df1 = pd.concat(Combined) 

group_size = 2500  

numbers = list(range(len(df1.index) // group_size)) * group_size

numbers.sort()

numbers = pd.Series(numbers)

DF_1 = pd.concat([df1, numbers], axis=1)      ## I think this line is the problem of my code and gives me ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3686225, 4), indices imply (2367075, 4)##

DF_1.columns = ['X','Y','Z','group number']

groups = DF_1.groupby('group number').filter(lambda x: len(x) == group_size)

print(groups)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
import numpy as np

def index_marks(nrows, chunk_size):
    return range(chunk_size, math.ceil(nrows / chunk_size) * chunk_size, chunk_size)

def split(dfm, chunk_size):
    indices = index_marks(dfm.shape[0], chunk_size)
    return np.split(dfm, indices)

# program loads the dataframe dfm.
df1 = pd.concat(Combined) 
group_size = 2500  

chunks = split(dfm, group_size)
for c in chunks:
    print("Shape: {}; {}".format(c.shape, c.index))
```

and you can operate on the chunks c and work away.